# How can I include an R code chunk within LaTeX code in an rmd file?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

The following does not work:

````
\begin{itemize}

  \item The first item
  \item 
    ```{r}
    x <- 3
    ```
  \item The third etc \ldots

\end{itemize}
````

Is there a way to do this or must I rewrite the file as an .rnw?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a markdown style list?

Comment: Can you do `\Sexpr{}` like in Sweave/knitr?

Comment: @tmpname12345 I was having trouble indenting code blocks to match the indentation of the preceding text in a list item. I figured out how to correctly indent a code block (not straightforward!) but I still wonder if what I'm asking is possible. There are other reasons why you might want to put a code block within LaTeX code: i.e., if I want to have multiple columns on a page (or slide) and have code in one of the columns.

Comment: It is possible. Pandoc does not modify stuff inside tex enviroments. Thus, you have to tell knitr to knit those code chunks as though the output file is latex as opposed to markdown. It involves modifying the [source and output hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/), but I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: It has been awhile since this was asked, but I wonder if you solved it @Michael. I think my current problem is related to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396080/how-can-you-put-table-into-a-header-with-knitr

Comment: It's probably possible but it's easier to just switch to LaTeX/.rnw at this point.